# Is it possible to do an action in the parent window after a child is closed JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to update an image in a parent window after a cchild is closed.
Is it possible to add a wait condition? So that the line `viewPort.setImage(imagedo.getImage());` happens after the window is closed?

```
@FXML
    void showGamma(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
            Stage gammaStage= new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GammaCorrection.fxml"));
            gammaStage.setTitle("PhotoShop");
            gammaStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 576, 280));
            gammaStage.setResizable(false);
            gammaStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            gammaStage.show();
            viewPort.setImage(imagedo.getImage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Stage.showAndWait()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait()) instead of `Stage.show()`. This call returns after the stage has been closed:

```
gammaStage.showAndWait();
```

Note: This does not work for the primary stage. Since you create the stage yourself though, this is not a problem.